# How do DownloadStringTaskAsync and DownloadStringAsync manage to not block the UI thread?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

As far as I know, they both do not have the "async" keyword. Do they both create a new thread when downloading? I've heard people say that they do not use a new thread. Then how does it do it?

The normal DownloadString method does indeed block the UI thread, but how do the other 2 methods manage to do it without using the "await" keyword to return from the method and wait until the operation is completed

Comment: From the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync?view=net-5.0): *"The resource is downloaded asynchronously using thread resources that are automatically allocated from the thread pool."*

Comment: Oh, wow. I did not see that. I've had this concern because of the same thing with TcpClient's ConnectAsync. the official documentation does not have information about whether it uses a thread from the thread pool or not.

Comment: Highly suggest HttpClient, it's interface and methods actually make sense :)

Comment: The `DownloadStringTaskAsync` is intended to be used with `await`. Are you using it without? Can you show us how you use it?

Comment: I do use it with await, since apparently it uses a new thread to download. However the official documentation also stated that you should not use a new thread with I/O bound related work. Downloading things is an I/O operation, however DownloadStringTaskAsync does indeed use a new thread to do the task. Why is that?

Comment: How do you know that the `DownloadStringTaskAsync` uses a new thread to do the task? AFAIK this is not true. The documentation that talks about "asynchronous downloading using thread resources" is misleading IMHO. The hardware used in order to fetch data from the web is the network card, not the CPU. And when we talk about threads we talk about the CPU. The concept of "threads" is not applicable to network cards or video cards or disk controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know, they both do not have the "async" keyword. Do they both create a new thread when downloading?

True, [they do not use `async`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1d9e50cb4735df46d3de0cee5791e97295eaf588/src/libraries/System.Net.WebClient/src/System/Net/WebClient.cs#L1655). But you don't have to use `async` in order to be asynchronous.

They do not create new threads, if by that you mean that they just queue the blocking work to the thread pool. They *do* "use thread resources" when the operation completes, though I would say that documentation is misleading.

> I've heard people say that they do not use a new thread. Then how does it do it?

See [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). In summary, true asynchronous I/O uses callbacks, which generally ends at a completion port, which in .NET is part of the thread pool. However, there is not a thread that is blocked doing the I/O; rather, the thread pool's I/O threads (not worker threads) are used to service the completion port work as it completes.

Comment: The blog has a lot of terms that I do not seem to understand very clearly. From what I think I understood is, I/O threads are not used by the user, but by the framework to complete tasks(in our case, I assume it uses I/O threads to download), and that's the difference between Worker and I/O threads.

Comment: I/O threads are used to complete tasks, yes. But they're not used to download. They would be used to complete the download task once the download completed.

Comment: The task of downloading is what hogs and blocks the UI thread then. I'm struggling to understand how .NET manages to do it without blocking. The blog seems to explain it very clearly I am sure but, It's just that there are lot of terms I do not get.

Comment: @Enlight: You can think of it as callbacks. The `Download*Async` method will request a download and register a callback. It then returns a task. When the download completes, the callback completes the task.

Comment: Can you please possibly show a visualization of the example you just did? From what I understood, If it requests a download, who downloads it? if the same thread downloads it, wouldn't it block?

Comment: @Enlight: This is a simplification, but the general gist is this. A download consists of two network messages: a request and a response. When a thread has sent the request, why does it need to sit around until the response comes in? It can just send the request and register a callback so that the app can handle the response when it arrives. There is no need for a thread just to sit and wait.

Comment: Right, yes. That makes sense now.What doesn't really make sense, is how it sets the thread to be free and not just wait around. With async methods, you can use the await keyword to return from the method and return later when it is finished. With DownloadStringAsync, it does not have the async keyword. I assume it is done with another way under the hood using DownloadStringAsync?

Comment: @Enlight: It uses `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to create a task that will be completed later.

Comment: Right, from what I understood, it creates a request and by returning a TaskCompletionSource, the thread does not have to wait around until it is finished. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes; by returning, the thread is unblocked.

Comment: "TaskCompletionSource turns something that is already asynchronous into a Task.", by doing that, does it internally use the "await" keyword to return?

Comment: @Enlight: No. It uses callbacks.

Comment: Right, so something along of: It requests a download, passes in a callback, returns and once it's finished it calls back to finish the operation

Comment: @Enlight: Yup.​